# Get argument types for function as a type instead of array

Tags: typescript, function, types

I want to get all arguments of a function as a type, for example:

```
postX(
    arg1: string;
    arg2: number;
    arg3?: string;
    options?: AxiosRequestConfig,
  ): AxiosPromise<void>;
```

I want to get a type as following:

```
type argsType = {
    arg1: string;
    arg2: number;
    arg3?: string;
    options?: AxiosRequestConfig,
  }
```

The `Parameters` helper doesn't work in this case since it will return an array of the args and not really a type constructed from those args:

```
(parameter) props: [arg1: string, arg2: number, arg3?: string, options?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a type"? There is no type for parameters separate from a function's type. You can have a function type which includes the parameters, or a tuple of the parameters - what you currently get. You seem to want something else other than those two but it's not clear what it is. Or if it's even possible.

Comment: @VLAZ, yeah I was sceptical if this can be acheived, as @ghybs mentioned in his answer what I'm trying to do is to convert the tuple retruned from `Parameters` to an object

Comment: What object? how exactly should it look? A tuple seems to be the natural representation - parameters are positional, so you'd want to know what the second or seventh is, for example. An object would need to be indexed by numbers at which point you have a tuple again. If you mean key/values with the *name* of the parameter - not possible. The names in tuples are not exposed. There would be numerous problems trying to work with their names. Moreover, such an object would be almost unusable, as you lose the positions of the arguments thus the real knowledge of what is what.

Comment: @VLAZ yes that's exactly what I meant to convert a named tuple into object literal type, which means a type with the parameters names and their values, but it seems that it's not possible